# woocommerce get_terms filter based on product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am just hoping that someone might help me.

My problem is in woocommerce, I would like to list terms for brands depending on the current product category.
But all I know for now is to list all terms and this is fine when in shop page but I also like to have a filter on product category and also to count available items for that product category.

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'parent'    =>  0
);
$terms = get_terms( 'yith_product_brand', $args );
foreach( $terms as $term ):
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term ); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a> <span class="count">(<?php echo $term->count; ?>)</span></li>
<?php
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What terms are you trying to include/exclude? Do you have any examples? For reference, both tags and categories are taxonomies and are meant to classify posts. they aren't meant to relate to one another so I suspect this could be very difficult.

Comment: Hi, 
I don't know hot to explain it correctly but basically I just want to list all brands and the taxonomy that I am using is yith_product_brand because I am using yith brands add on. But I am having a problem because I want to list all brands that are only available in the current product category page.
I only know how to list all brands but I don't know how to filter it the right way.

Thanks