# How to display terms that fall under a category and a taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I am using Woocommerce to sell products.
I am having trouble using multiple conditional tags for my product category archive pages.
My products are categorized by Adult, Child, and Infant. 
Then I created a custom non-hierarchical taxonomy for my products called "Artist" to further distinguish the products.
Here is a sample product: "Really Cool T-Shirt" - Product Category: Adult - Artist: Led Zeppelin.

Adult: Led Zeppelin, AC/DC, Metallica

Child: ACDC, Black Sabbath

Infant: ACDC, Nirvana

Lets say I'm on the Child archive page. On that page I want to display a dropdown list of all the artists that are also part of the Child category (ACDC, Black Sabbath). So the Adult archive page will have a dropdown containing Led Zeppelin, AC/DC, Metallica and so forth. I end up displaying all the artists for each archive template or getting WP errors when I try other conditional tags such as

```
if(is_product_category('infant')){ }
```

Below is the closest I have gotten with out any errors.

```
<select>
  <option value="" selected>Search by Artist</option>
  <?php
    $terms = get_terms('artist');
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {?>
      <option value="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name . " (" . $term->count . ")"; ?></option>
    <?php };
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You have this similar related post: [woocommerce get_terms filter based on product category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695927/woocommerce-get-terms-filter-based-on-product-category) with an explicit comment from **helgatheviking** very  active on woocommerce questions. She said: For reference, both tags and categories are taxonomies and are meant to classify posts. they aren't meant to relate to one another so I suspect this could be very difficult.

Comment: After that, when searching over internet on this subject, there is [this support plugin thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/product-categories-filter-now-showing) related to this free plugin [WooCommerce Products Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/) with his commercial version too. Then another commercial related plugin  [WOOF](http://codecanyon.net/item/woof-woocommerce-products-filter/11498469) …

Comment: Her answer does put things into perspective.  I prefer not using plugins but I will definitely  check it out. Thank you.

Comment: Looking to the code of **WooCommerce Products Filter** will certainly give you some tracks about how to solve this. Personally i often get inspiration this way.

Comment: how are you making your archive pages? `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` ?

Comment: I am using archive-product.php for my product categories and taxonomy-artist.php for my custom taxonomy archive page.